# AWS Client VPN for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-vpn

I have an EC2 instance running MySQL. I want to connect via VPN using the port 3306.
After I connect with the VPN, I'm not been able to connect to my MySQL using a VPN endpoint using MySQL Workbench. I tried to ping the EC2 instance from my local machine when vpn is connected using the private ipv4 address too without success.

I configured the connection on AWS by creating and importing OpenSSL certificates, deploying AWS Directory Services and Deploying an AWS Client VPN Endpoint.

The AWS Client VPN Endpoint under "Target network associations" has the same VPC where the instance is located. Security group and subnet is the same as the instance. Under "Authorization rules" I allowed all traffic with destination CIDR of 0.0.0.0/0 and under "Route table" the target subnet is the same subnet as the EC2 instance.

The Security group that my instance and the client vpn endpoint share has the following inbound rules:

- Allow UDP to the port 443 to the Client CIDR of the VPN
- Allow all TCP in all ports for itself (same Security group)

On the other hand I can see my connection working under "Connections" in Client VPN Endpoint

What I'm missing?

Comment: `ping` only works if the security group permits ICMP traffic. It isn't a good way to test network connections in AWS. Much better to try and get the desired port working.

Comment: A good test would be to _temporarily_ open the Security Group on the database to all IP addresses (not just limited to incoming traffic from itself). This will help identify whether the problem lies in the Security Group configuration. You could also try using the [Reachability Analyzer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html) to identify the blockage.

Comment: Ok, now I'm testing with ´telnet ip-address 3306´ and it is a security group configuration problem because when I open the port to all IP addresses I can reach the port and connect via MySQL Workbench

Comment: I recreated the VPN endpoint with another CIDR Client IP range and now it works. Im not sure but maybe the previous CIDR was overlaping